# how to read FormData object in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, file, laravel-5.4

I am trying to ajax submit form to a Laravel 5 controller method. I understand that in php, you can define a FormData object, append the input fields to the object and send it to the server where you can now extract the values using the input field names.

Like so:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
formdata.append('file_name', 'some_file_name_from_form.png');
```

When `form_data` is sent as the `data` in the ajax call, I can get the file in PHP by using the `$_FILES['file_name']['name'];`.

So I tried this same logic in a Laravel controller method. I tried just to grab the name of the file in the `$request` object but only got null.

My controller method:

```
public function postImage(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->get('file_name');

    dd($file);
}
```

But when I `dd` the whole request, I see this weird object:

> array:1 [
>     "file_name" => UploadedFile {#199
>       -test: false
>       -originalName: "work-fitness_00255959.png"
>       -mimeType: "image/png"
>       -size: 34215
>       -error: 0
>       #hashName: null
>       path: "/tmp"
>       filename: "phpVodsUg"
>       basename: "phpVodsUg"
>       pathname: "/tmp/phpVodsUg"
>       extension: ""
>       realPath: "/tmp/phpVodsUg"
>       aTime: 2017-06-04 12:42:26
>       mTime: 2017-06-04 12:42:26
>       cTime: 2017-06-04 12:42:26
>       inode: 17573243
>       size: 34215
>       perms: 0100600
>       owner: 1000
>       group: 1000
>       type: "file"
>       writable: true
>       readable: true
>       executable: false
>       file: true
>       dir: false
>       link: false
>     }
>   ]

Please how do I get the image sent through `FormData()` object in Ajax through it's name?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this.

```
// get the `UploadedFile` object
$file = $request->file('file_name');
$file = $request->file_name;

// get the original file name
$filename = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
$filename = $request->file_name->getClientOriginalName();
```

Check out the documentation for more information https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

The api methods available on the uploaded file http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

Answer (score 2):

The code bellow is working for me:

```
$("#your_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr("action");
    var data = new FormData(form[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType : false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

my problem was in property contentType. So, I set as false and it's ok!