# Vuejs won't send correct data

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have image field, when I change the image `it does` change the image and before I send it to back-end I can see the values are correct, but sent data values are empty!

#### Code

`Commented`

```
save_changes() {
    /* eslint-disable */
    if (!this.validateForm) return;
    console.log("image: ", this.data_local.image); // new image data are present
    this.$http
    .put(
        "/api/admin/posts/meta/" + this.$route.params.id,
        this.data_local, // new image data is empty!
        {
        headers: {
            Authorization: localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
        },
        }
    )
    .then((res) => {
    }
    //rest of it...
},
update_avatar(event) {
    this.dialogVisible = true;
    this.dialogImageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    this.data_local.image = event.target.files[0]; // this is where I sent selected image and pass it to my `data_local` array objects
},
```

#### Screenshots

[image: one]

[image: two]

**Any suggestions?**

## Update

header request

[image: three]

Comment: i do not understand that you show us the `response` tab and write to it `sent data to back end` well thats the data you receive from the backend... you should go to the `header` tab and scroll down to the parameters and show us that

Comment: @Ifaruki I receive that because I dumped my data in controller to see what I am getting. and as you see controller says that I'm receiving image as empty.

Comment: it would still be great to show us the header tab to see if the data is really not sended to the server

Comment: @Ifaruki updated

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to send it as an FormData

```
let file = this.data_local.image
let image = URL.createObjectURL(file)
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", image);
formData.append("id", 71);
formData.append(....)
this.$http
.put(
    "/api/admin/posts/meta/" + this.$route.params.id,
     formData, 
    {
    headers: {
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
    },
    }
)
.then((res) => {
}
```

The headers should look something like this:

[image]

Your image should have this `(binary)`

Comment: it just gives my empty formData `formData:  FormData {}` nothing passes to controller.

Comment: yes the head is like your edited part `binary` but can't get any of the data in back-end not sure why!

Comment: @mafortis what backend lang do you use

Comment: @mafortis maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354370/how-to-read-formdata-object-in-laravel

Comment: That I have, issue for me is not how to store the image but not getting it in beck-end. formData sends my image value as `image {}`

Comment: @mafortis i have update my answer take a look

Comment: it sends `blob`